# XAMPP and Magento - Need to change ports?

Tags: php, magento, xampp, localhost, ports

Today I tried to access localhost/magento and the page would not load. Then, I just tried using localhost/phpmyadmin and the same thing. I read somewhere that the default port could be in use and cause this issue, so I changed the listener to 100 and localhost:100/phpmyadmin worked. Now, Magento gets an error every time I try to access it.

I've tried changing the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url tables to http://localhost:100/magento/ and manually deleting my var/cache folder contents... still no luck.

Is there something I'm missing or an extra step I need to do with magento?

By the way I have it installed on XAMPP with windows 7 64-bit. Everything was working fine the day before.

edit: error codes

Module "Practice_OneStepCheckout" requires module "Mage_CatalogInventorty".

Trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(849): Mage::throwException('Module "Practic...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(812): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I'm missing or an extra step I need to do with magento?

Nope, it should work out of the box. What is the error you get?

I can recommend to use vhosts, that wil save you allot of time in the future: http://butlerccwebdev.net/support/testingserver/vhosts-setup-win.html

(Also, the most common port 80 issue under windows/xampp users is TeamViewer)

Comment: Apparently, 'Mage_CatalogInventory' is missing or disabled. 
Or there is a typo in 'app/etc/Practice_OneStepCheckout.xml'